# push code back to TFVC repository on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I am trying to push back code to a **TFVC** through a Azure Devops pipeline but I cannot make it work. I am using a `powershell` task and `tf` commands to automatically commit changes through a processing that happens on a pipeline. The output of this processing should be pushed back on the working TFVC repository.

First I create a sample file on the Pipeline.Workspace on sources folder.

*Command line step.*

```
echo "content 1 2 3" >  $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/file_created_by_pipeline.txt
ls $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s
```

Then I try to commit changes back on repository.

*Powershell task:*

```
cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s
tf add .*.txt /resursive; 
tf checkin .*.txt /comment "added new files" /recursive  /force
```

*Issue:*

```
No changes were matched by any arguments
```

During the run of the pipeline I have also to provide codes based on the OAuth 2.0 Device Flow authentication

Also when I set the `TF_BYPASS_BROWSER_LOGIN=true` variable on the pipeline I get

> Default credentials are unavailable because no Kerberos ticket or
> other authentication token is available.

My goal is to push changes back on the working repository which is the source of code for this pipeline. Also I need to bypass the Oath authentication. I have already selected the allow scripts to access the OAuth token on the agent job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [tried my TFVC extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-tfvc-tasks)? They were made for this exact purpose.

[image]

Alternatively, you can try using the OAuth token of the pipeline to check in:

```
& tf vc checkin .*.txt /comment "added new files" /recursive /force
   /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
```

Make sure to configure the pipeline so it can access the token:

[image]

If needed add the access token to the PowerShell Task's environment variable section:

[image]

Comment: I noticed a strange behavior on the task of the adding new files for checkin. It seems that new folders are not added. Is that normal? Could I override this issue? I use files to add with a regex like `filesdir/*`

Comment: No clue. @GeralexGR it's been years since I really worked in TFVC and I've not had your issue (or never had your usecase). If you can give me a very specific reproducible case in the GitHub repos issues, I may be able to investigate. I've essentially converted the c# of `tf.exe` in PowerShell, you could try adding a call to tf.exe to pend the changes prior to the check-in task performing the check-in.